# Qual a diferença entre os usos de "casal" e "par"?

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras, diferenças, sinônimos

**TL;DR**: Não há dúvida de que estas duas palavras guardam bastante similaridade entre si, e podem até ser sinônimas em muitos contextos, mas qual é a regra geral que determina o uso preferencial de uma e não da outra?

## Contexto

A dúvida surgiu quando, ao consultar um livro antigo de algoritmos, o tradutor escolheu a expressão *casamento perfeito* para expressar o significado de *[perfect matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory))*, um algoritmo que busca agrupar em duplas todos os elementos de um conjunto, respeitando os requisitos de cada elemento. O livro dava como exemplo o *casamento* entre um grupo de doze alunos, sendo seis de cada gênero, com o objetivo de formar *casais* de alunos.

Esta tradução é bastante incomum, sendo a norma geral as expressões [*emparelhamento perfeito* ou *acoplamento perfeito*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoplamento_(teoria_dos_grafos)). Isto porque, apesar dos alunos formarem *casais*, os elementos de outros conjuntos não necessariamente os formam. Por exemplo, é possível formar *pares* cliente-fornecedor, mas usar a expressão *casal* cliente-fornecedor me soa bastante estranho. Casais, portanto, seria um caso bastante específico dentre as possibilidades de pares formados pelo algoritmo.

Os dicionários [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/casal), [Aurélio](https://dicionariodoaurelio.com/casal) e [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/casal) listam estas como definições do verbete *casal*: (ênfases minhas)

> ca·sal  (latim *casalis*, -e, relativo à quinta, à casa)
>
> substantivo masculino
>
> 1. **Par** formado por macho e fêmea.
> 2. **Par** formado pelos cônjuges.
> 3. Conjunto de duas pessoas que têm uma relação sentimental e/ou sexual.
> 4. Propriedade rústica menos importante que a quinta.
> 5. Pequena povoação. = LUGAREJO
> 6. **Conjunto formado por duas coisas iguais ou semelhantes. = PAR**

E estas definições para o verbete *par*: ([Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/par), [Aurélio](https://dicionariodoaurelio.com/par), [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/PAR))

> par  (latim *par*, *paris*, igual, semelhante, macho ou fêmea de um par,
> esposa, marido, par, **casal**)
>
> substantivo masculino
>
> 5. Conjunto de duas pessoas, particularmente, marido e mulher.
> 6. **Sociedade de dois. = DUPLA, PARELHA**
> 7. Cada uma das pessoas que constituem uma dupla na dança.
> 8. Pessoa igual a outra em posição social.
> 9. O macho ou a fêmea de um casal de aves.
> 10. **Conjunto de dois objetos da mesma espécie**.
> 11. Peça de vestuário ou utensílio composto de duas partes iguais.

Pelas definições dos dicionários, fiquei com a impressão de que *casal* indicaria um relacionamento romântico, enquanto *par* seria usado nas demais situações. No entanto, o uso corrente parece legitimar o emprego de *casal* para contextos onde os elementos não parecem estar associados desta forma:

> [Segundo informações do site CGN, uma mulher de 46 anos foi presa pela polícia acusada de estuprar os próprios filhos, um casal de nove e doze anos de idade. A prisão foi realizada na manhã desta quinta-feira (26), em Curitiba, no Paraná.](https://noticias.bol.uol.com.br/ultimas-noticias/brasil/2014/06/26/mae-e-presa-acusada-de-estuprar-dois-filhos-de-nove-e-doze-anos-no-pr.htm)

Na notícia, "casal de filhos" indica que não somente são duas crianças, como também é um menino e uma menina.

> [Brasil 1995 - Casal de moedas 10 centavos e 25 centavos da rara série FAO](http://www.philatelia.lel.br/peca.asp?ID=1739392)

No leilão, "casal de moedas" indica que não somente são duas moedas, mas que, juntas, elas formam uma combinação única e completa.

Nestas duas situações, embora o uso de *par* não causasse uma alteração profundamente significativa no sentido, a palavra *casal* contém mais significado do que simplesmente "conjunto de dois semelhantes". Seriam estas exceções à regra? Ou estaria a minha interpretação enganada quanto aos usos das duas palavras?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52444/discussion-on-question-by-ramon-melo-qual-a-diferenca-entre-os-usos-de-casal-e).

Answer (score 1):

Ao que eu pude ver, sua explicação está certa, e os termos **par** e **casal** foram usados corretamente. Acredito que não haja uma regra geral que define o uso dos dois, e onde eles devem ser usados, porém, tenho uma pequena sugestão que poderia ajuda-lo a distinguir o uso de ambas palavras:

**Casal** - não precisa ser necessariamente namorado e namorada, marido e mulher, por exemplo: existe casal de irmãos (Irmão e irmã). Para formar um Casal, só é preciso haver 2 gêneros opostos - *Um homem e uma mulher*.

**Par** - par é normalmente usado com objetos (*sapatos, tênis, chapéu*) um uso constante da palavra par, refere-se à: Par de sapatos, par de meias.. Tudo que vem em dois objetos, mas que não tem um gênero especifico, o que é o caso do sapato, da meia, da bota.. Eles não têm um gênero específico (eles não são nem homem nem mulher), eles são apenas objetos. Dado os fatos, é facilmente perceptível que a palavra **par** é normalmente utilizada com objetos sem gênero.

Essas são as explicações e sugestões mais precisas que eu consegui pensar, esse seria o único meio de distinguir ambas palavras:

> Casal

- uma dupla de dois sexos opostos - Homem e mulher

> Par

- objetos que normalmente vêm em pares, mas que não têm um sexo definido - par de meias, de botas, de sapatos, de roupas, de chinelos..

Comment: Na dança e no ténis, tens pares e não casais. E se vires [aqui, *fazem um belo par*](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&espv=2&biw=1242&bih=580&tbs=sbd%3A1&tbm=bks&q=%22fazem+um+belo+par%22&oq=%22fazem+um+belo+par%22&gs_l=serp.3...5547.6802.0.7418.6.6.0.0.0.0.103.577.4j2.6.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.4.381...30i10k1.eGbW2WFdhl8) refere-se quase sempre a pessoas.

Comment: @Jacinto - Tênis - sapato.
Sim, é verdade, hoje em dia é muito usado *formam um belo par*, porém é uma expressão idiomática, o que significa que pode variar entre os estados que é usado. Em Pernambuco (Estado que atualmente estou morando), é bem comum pessoas usarem ambas expressões *formam um belo casal* e *formam um belo par*. Portanto, expressões deveriam ser deixadas de lado aqui, uma vez que podem variar baseado no estado ou lugar que são usadas.

Comment: Não, não estou a falar de sapatos. Um jogo de ténis pode ser disputado por singulares (um contra um) ou por pares (dois contra dois). E expressões como *fazem/formam um belo par* já se usam há muito tempo, e não só em Pernambuco. Este significado de *par* vem em qualquer dicionário.

Comment: @Jacinto - Apesar de não ser gramaticalmente correto, e sim idiomaticamente correto. Brasil é envolvido de gírias e expressões que são diariamente criadas, é normal que já esteja incluída no dicionário.

Comment: Complicado definir _gramaticalmente correto_ vs _idiomaticamente correto_ quando o uso já é consagrado por tanto tempo. Mas o principal é que, seja qual for o meio, existem centenas de referências de _par_ a uma dupla de gêneros opostos.

Comment: @Ramon Mesmo muito tempo: já vem pelo menos do século XVIII (vê [dicionário de Moraes Silva de 1789](https://books.google.pt/books?id=rwVdAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA155&dq=%22o+marido+e+mulher+fe+dizem+hum+par%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihis3Ep-fRAhUKvRQKHVWDAu8Q6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%22o%20marido%20e%20mulher%20fe%20dizem%20hum%20par%22&f=false).

Comment: Haseo, em que dicionário, gramática, ou outra autoridade te baseias para afirmar que este uso de *par* não é gramaticalmente correto ou que é gíria? Os dicionário que eu vi não dizem nada disso. Este uso é comum também em Portugal já vem do século XVIII.

Comment: @Jacinto - A diferença é que eu uso o Português Brasileiro, e se não tem no dicionário, é exatamente por isso, a diferença entre esses dois termos é que **par** é normalmente usado para coisas, e não gêneros, **casal**, por outro lado, é sempre usado em gêneros, pessoas, animais.. - Há muitas diferenças entre o Português e o Português Brasileiro, mas isso não vem ao caso, é só uma questão de duas formas idiomáticas.

Comment: Haseo, *par* no sentido de duas pessoas **vem em todos os dicionários** que eu consultei, incluindo três dicionários brasileiros; nenhum deles diz que isto é gíria ou agramatical.

Comment: @Jacinto - Poderia manda-los para mim? Por gentileza?

Comment: [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=par); [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/par); [Dicio](https://www.dicio.com.br/par/); O Houaiss só tenho em papel.

Comment: @Jacinto - É razoável, mas ainda sim acho que é muito informal usar **Par** com gêneros. Mas..

Comment: Idiomaticamente eu diria "um par de polícias"; mesmo sendo um homem e uma mulher, "um casal de polícias" soaria estranho. "Um par de gatos a brincar". "Um par de crianças na piscina". Mas "têm dois filhos" ou "têm um casalinho", e não "têm um par de filhos" (que me soa como "têm alguns filhos").

Answer (score 0):

**casal** > **par**

Par - conjunto de 2 semelhantes.

- Um par de meias pode-se referir a 1 meia azul + 1 meia vermelha.
- Um "par cliente-fornecedor" está correto. Ambos são da mesma "espécie" (aplicações ou máquinas) mas são independentes. A função de cliente é definida pela origem de um pedido e a função servidor pela origem da resposta.

Casal - conjunto de 2 semelhantes com uma forte relação/ligação de dependência.

- Um casal de meias refere-se a 1 meia esquerda + 1 meia direita (normalmente da mesma cor).
- Um casal de irmãos refere-se a géneros opostos (uma vez que acrescenta algo à relação familiar).
- A expressão "casal cliente-fornecedor" só poderia fazer sentido num contexto onde 1 máquina apenas fará pedidos a 1 outra máquina, que servirá respostas apenas à máquina anterior.